# Server reboots when running Veeam PowersShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, veeam

I have created the below script that what it does is to kill a specific Veeam process related to a job name. The issue is that it have to first find the the job id, then search in processes description for that ID and kill it. But i think somehow is making a infinite loop that in some cases when i have to run it multiple times (because there could be more than one process related to the ID), it reboots the server.

```
$JobName = Read-Host "Enter Job name"
$JobID = Get-VBRJob | select name, ID | Where {$_.name -like $JobName} | select -expand ID
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%$JobID%'" Call Terminate
```

Comment: I kind of shiver seeing stuff along the lines of `$_.Name -like <stuff>` and `"CommandLine Like '%<stuff>%'` when it's about terminating something. Is it impossible to know the exact value of something in any of the steps? Some sort of validation of what you have in `$JobID` would seem mandatory to me. If it's empty you just might call terminate on ALL processes.

Comment: Sounds logic. Yep. How can i set like mandatory to have an input?. In other hand, maybe i can first call for a list of jobs and select the one that is named as the input?.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the (any) Veeam PS-module but wouldn't `Get-VBRJob -Name "<my_exact_job_name>"` get the one desired (assuming it's known by name) job and only that one job? If you somehow must run the `where`-clause anyway, try changing the matching to something like `| where { $_.Name -eq $JobName }` instead.